# Find whether $f(n) = o(g(n))$ or $g(n) = o(f(n))$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

> Find whether $f(x) = O(g(n))$ or $g(n) = O(f(x))$ where
>   $$
>   f(n) = (\log n)^{\log n} 
>     \quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad
>   g(n) = 2^{(\log_2n)^2}
> $$

I found that $f(n) = n^{ \log {\log n}}$, but can't simplify $g(n)$.

Comment: Your formula for $f$ is slightly wrong - you probably want $n^{\log\log n}$ there. You may find it easier still to write both as functions of the form $2^{a(n)}$ and then compare the corresponding functions $a()$ - but be careful; this slightly modifies your conditions for the $f\in O(g)$ relationship and you need to understand how it changes them.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for correction. Your idea worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n) = \Bbb e ^{(\log \log n) \log n} = \big( \Bbb e ^{ \log n} \big) ^{\log \log n} = n ^{\log \log n}$.

$g(n) = 2^ {(\log _2 n) (\log _2 n)} = \big( 2^ {\log _2 n} \big) ^{\log _2 n} = n ^{\log _2 n} = n ^{\frac {\log n} {\log 2}}$.

Therefore, $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {f(n)} {g(n)} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} n ^{\log \log n - \frac {\log n} {\log 2}} = \infty ^{- \infty} = 0$, therefore $f(n) = o (g(n))$ (mind you, it is "little o", not "big O"!).

Comment: Little o implies big O

Answer (score 1):

$g(n) = \left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)^{\log_2 n} = O(n^{\log n})$

$f(n) = e^{(\log \log n) \log n} = O(n^{\log \log n})$

So $g$ asymptotically grows faster than $f$, so $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and not the other way around